# How to sort a string's characters alphabetically?

Tags: ruby, string, sorting

For Array, there is a pretty `sort` method to rearrange the sequence of elements. I want to achieve the same results for a String.

For example, I have a string `str = "String"`, I want to sort it alphabetically with one simple method to `"ginrSt"`.

Is there a native way to enable this or should I include mixins from `Enumerable`?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The [`chars` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chars) returns an enumeration of the string's characters.

```
str.chars.sort.join
#=> "Sginrt"
```

To sort case insensitively:

```
str.chars.sort(&:casecmp).join
#=> "ginrSt"
```

Comment: or `str.chars.sort(&:casecmp).join`

Answer (score 15):

Also (just for fun)

```
str = "String"
str.chars.sort_by(&:downcase).join
#=> "ginrSt"
```

Comment: I like the sort_by method more, because it is more clear and easy

Answer (score 3):

```
str.unpack("c*").sort.pack("c*")
```

Comment: add some explanation to it. what exactly are you trying to say?

Answer (score 3):

You can transform the string into an array to sort:

```
'string'.split('').sort.join
```

Answer (score 1):

If you deal with Unicode text, you might prefer to use [`String#grapheme_clusters`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-grapheme_clusters):

```rb
"a\u0300e".chars.sort.join
=> "aè" # diacritic moved!
"a\u0300e".grapheme_clusters.sort.join
=> "àe" # expected result
```