# How to sort a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a string's characters alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464065/how-to-sort-a-strings-characters-alphabetically)

Assuming there is a simple string 
str = "bacd"
I want to sort it so that the result contains
result = "abcd"

How do I do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 10):

Tokland's comment is so nice it deserves to be a full-fledged answer:

```
str.chars.sort.join
```

This works in Ruby 1.8 and 1.9.

You can find the Ruby Doc [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chars).

Answer (score 3):

Nice and simple:

```
str = 'bacd'
p str.split('').sort.join # => "abcd"
```

Comment: marginally nicer: `str.chars.sort.join`