# Finding 'tidy numbers' in Scala

Tags: ruby, scala, integer

A tidy number is a number whose digits are in non-decreasing order, e.g. 1234. Here is a way of finding tidy numbers written in Ruby:

```
def tidy_number(n)
  n.to_s.chars.sort.join.to_i == n
end

p tidy_number(12345678)     # true
p tidy_number(12345878)     # false
```

I tried to write the same thing in Scala and arrived at the following:

```
object MyClass {
def tidy_number(n:Int) = n.toString.toList.sorted.mkString.toInt == n;

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println(tidy_number(12345678))        // true
      println(tidy_number(12345878))        // false
    }
}
```

The only way I could do it in Scala was by converting an integer to a string to a list and then sorting the list and going back again. My question: is there a better way? 'Better' in the sense there are fewer conversions. I'm mainly looking for a concise piece of Scala but I'd be grateful if someone pointed out a more concise way of doing it in Ruby as well.

Comment: `"The methods .toList and .mkString are not needed".sorted == "       ..LSTaaddddeeeeeeghhiikmmnnnnooorrssttttt"`

Comment: "The only way I could do it in Scala was by converting an integer to a string to a list and then sorting the list and going back again" this is exactly what the Ruby code is doing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sorted` on strings in Scala, so

```
def tidy_number(n: Int) = {
  val s = n.toString
  s == s.sorted
}
```

Doing it in two parts also avoids an extra toInt conversion.

I've never used ruby, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9464065/5986907) suggests you're doing it the best way

Answer (score 5):

You can check each adjacent pair of digits to make sure that the first value is <= the second:

```
  def tidy_number(n:Int) =
    n.toString.sliding(2,1).forall(p => p(0) <= p(1))
```

#### Update following from helpful comments

As noted in the comments, this fails for single-digit numbers. Taking this and another comment together gives this:

```
  def tidy_number(n:Int) =
    (" "+n).sliding(2,1).forall(p => p(0) <= p(1))
```

Being even more pedantic it would be better to convert back to `Int` before comparing so that you don't rely on the sort order of the characters representing digits being the same as the sort order for the digits themselves.

```
  def tidy_number(n:Int) =
    (" "+n).sliding(2,1).forall(p => p(0).toInt <= p(1).toInt)
```

Comment: that looks like a really odd equality check :)  `p => p(0) <= p(1)`. nice technique though

Comment: Doesn't work with numbers whose string representation is shorter than 2. But does do the job in linear rather than loglinear time!

Comment: (" " + n)... gets round the single digit problem and saves typing toString

Comment: ...which in Ruby would be `n < 10 || n.digits.each_cons(2).all? { |n,m| n >= m }`. It's `n <= m`, rather than `n <= m` because [Integer#digits](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits) returns an array whose first element is the one's digit of `n`. See also [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons). `||` is logical or.

Comment: `toInt` will error for `" "`, so the more thorough version doesn't work with it. If repeated numbers are OK, `"0" + n` is better

Answer (score 1):

> The only way I could do it in Scala was by converting an integer to a string to a list and then sorting the list and going back again. My question: is there a better way?

`String` conversion and sorting is not required.

```
def tidy_number(n :Int) :Boolean =
  Iterator.iterate(n)(_/10)
          .takeWhile(_>0)
          .map(_%10)
          .sliding(2)
          .forall{case Seq(a,b) => a >= b
                  case _ => true} //is a single digit "tidy"?
```

Better? Hard to say. One minor advantage is that the math operations (`/` and `%`) stop after the first `false`. So for the `Int` value `1234567890` there are only 3 ops (2 modulo and 1 division) before the result is returned. (Digits are compared in reverse order.)

But seeing as an `Int` is, at most, only 10 digits long, I'd go with Joel Berkeley's answer just for its brevity.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def tidyNum(n:Int) = {
  var t =n; var b = true;
  while(b && t!=0){b=t%10>=(t/10)%10;t=t/10};b  
 }
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> tidyNum(12345678)
res20: Boolean = true

scala> tidyNum(12343678)
res21: Boolean = false

scala> tidyNum(12)
res22: Boolean = true

scala> tidyNum(1)
res23: Boolean = true

scala> tidyNum(121)
res24: Boolean = false
```

This can work for any size with just the modification of type such as `Long` or `BigInt` in function signature like `tidyNum(n:Long)` or `tidyNum(n:BigInt)` as below:

```
 def tidyNum(n:BigInt) = {
  var t =n; var b = true;
  while(b && t!=0){b=t%10>=(t/10)%10;t=t/10};b
}

scala> tidyNum(BigInt("123456789"))
res26: Boolean = true

scala> tidyNum(BigInt("1234555555555555555555555567890"))
res29: Boolean = false

scala> tidyNum(BigInt("123455555555555555555555556789"))
res30: Boolean = true
```

And the `BigInt` can be used for types `Int, Long` as well.